# How can you prevent tax total GL impact for NetSuite transactions?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is there a way that if someone wants to prevent GL impact for a transaction's tax total (native taxtotal field) that this can easily be done with SuiteScript, for posting transactions?

Comment: What Rusty said below, A custom GL Lines Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with using a custom GL plugin that reverses the tax impact on the GL